# square the elements of a sorted list and give the output in sorted order

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

> Given a sorted list of integers, square the elements and give the
>   output in sorted order.
>
> For example, given [-9, -2, 0, 2, 3], return [0, 4, 4, 9, 81].

My solution 1:

```
const square = el => el * el;
const sortAsc = (a, b) => a - b;
const sortSquare = list => list
  .map(square)
  .sort(sortAsc);

console.log(sortSquare([-9, -2, 0, 2, 3]));
```

My solution 2:

```
const sortSquare2 = list => {
  list.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a) - Math.abs(b));
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = Math.pow(list[i], 2);
  }
  return list;
};

console.log(sortSquare2([-9, -2, 0, 2, 3]));
```

Is there a faster solution? I have the feeling you can do something with the fact that the list is sorted to begin with. But I can't think of a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start at both ends and compare these values, you can step down towards the center, unshifting the values, squaring them and unshifting them to the resulting array.

You don't need to square the values until you add them to the array. You can compare to find the greater value by negating the left side.

One \$O(n)\$ solution is as follows

```js
function sortSquares(arr) {
    const res = [];
    var start = 0; end = arr.length - 1, idx = end;
    while (start <= end) {
        res[idx--] = (-arr[start] > arr[end] ? arr[start++] : arr[end--]) ** 2;
    }
    return res;
}

// Test code
[
    [-9,-5,-0.5,0.6,1, 2, 3,8],
    [1, 2, 3,8],
    [-10, -8, -3, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1],    
    [0.6,1, 2, 3,8],
    [-9,-6,-3,-2,-1],
    [-9,-6,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,6,9],
].forEach(a => log(a, sortSquares(a)));


function log(data, data1) {
   data = "[" + data + "] -=>> [" + data1 + "]";
   info.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("div"),{textContent: data}));
}
```

```html
<code id="info"></code>
```

Comment: Is it really a good idea to fill an array with `unshift`? It sounds inefficient. You could easily put each element at its correct position right away. `res[end-start] = ...`

Comment: @Kruga Good point, i was not on the ball.

Comment: The resulting code is simply beautiful and solves the problem efficiently. Masterful I have to say.

Hmm....may I have a tiny question? I just noticed, is there a reason why you chose an if/else over a ternary operator?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Eeeck my 3rd stuff up for the day... :(.The original version unshifted to the array rather than assigned to an array index and thus was not suited for a ternary. Good call `res[idx--] = (-arr[start] > arr[end] ?  arr[start++] : arr[end--]) ** 2;` is far more concise.

Comment: May I ask what is your favorite language and why?

Comment: @thadeuszlay That changes over time, currently I spend most of my time writing JS, it's a great language. Main reason, no writing overhead (type declarations, casting, etc) It has a great set of API's, including debugging (dev tools) is cross platform and will practically run on anything. It's only downside is its sandboxes environment, and  speed, for that I prefer good old C. C gives you a direct link to the hardware and blinding speed.

Comment: Since when are writing Software and what do you think is the best way to improve as a software developer?

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a functional programming and ES6 related thing instead of a performance improvement

---

## [Pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree)

Pointfree is a programming paradigm in which you try to avoid the argument you want to transform.

So we could avoid `sortSquare = list => ...`

```
const sortSquare = compose(
  sort(sortAsc), 
  map(square)
)
```

Where `sort` and `map` are [curried functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying) and `compose` is a [composition of two functions](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/manipulating-functions/function-composition/a/finding-and-evaluating-composite-functions) in the form of \$f ∘ g\$ which means \$f(g(x))\$

```js
const map = f => xs => xs.map(f)
const sort = f => xs => xs.sort(f)

const compose = (f, g) => x => f(g(x))

const square = el => el ** 2
const sortAsc = (a, b) => a - b

const sortSquare = compose(
  sort(sortAsc),
  map(square)
)

console.log(sortSquare([-9, -2, 0, 2, 3]));
```

---

## [Exponentiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)) in ES6

Since ES6 it is possible to use the `**`-operator.

> ```
> const square = el => el * el;
> ```

```
const square = el => el ** 2;
```